# android how to use startActivityForResult for doing action after coming back from mail composer

Tags: android, email, android-activity

I'm sending an email, but I need to go to a different activity when the user comes back from the email composer, how to accomplish this?

here my code,
//send mail

```
String prestartTypeString = prestartType;
String to = "juanman234@gmail.com";
String subject = "Pre-Start - "+prestartTypeString;
String message = fullName+" has sent you a Pre-Start checklist for equipment "
                  +registrationNumber+".\n" + "Please find PDF report attached.
    \n\nNeed help viewing this report\nEmail us anytime at\nhello@tiks.com.au";

Intent email = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{ to});

email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message);

//attachment
Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                                                              "generato.pdf"));
email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);

//need this to prompts email client only
email.setType("message/rfc822");

startActivity(Intent.createChooser(email, "Choose an Email client :"));

setResult(RESULT_OK, email);
```

I have checked

> startActivityForResult();

but dont have clear if this is the way to do it, and have not make it work

so how to trigger a function when the user comes back from the email intent?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

start the activity with startActivityForResult(); and override the following method

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            //place your code here what you want to do when result is returned, in your  case go to different activity
}
```

This method is invoked when the called activity returns the result